# Exporting SVG to PDF in a offline TideSDK webapp

Tags: php, javascript, python, pdf, svg

I have an offline HTML5/CSS/JS app built with TideSDK in which a bar chart is drawn with Highcharts as an SVG "tag" using data entered by the user. I need to export this chart in a PDF document, which will also contain text and tables.

As it is an offline app I can't use the export module included in Highcharts (except the getSVG() method) or other solutions like DocRaptor.

I'm open to use another JS plugin for drawing the chart, but I really love the "look and feel" and the features of Highcharts graphs.

As you may know, with TideSDK I can embed Python, PHP or Perl scripts/modules in my app (I prefer avoid Perl as I've never used it).

The other limitation is that I cannot ask to the final users to install another software than mine, so I can't use `wkhtmltopdf` with PHP. Except if I manage to install it through my app in a transparent process (not sure it is particularly easy to do).

After having search for several days, my final idea is to use the CairoSVG Python module to export the graph in a first PDF. Then I will find a JS (jsPDF) or Python tool to include this PDF in the final PDF containing text and tables.

I will start to test this solution soon and let you know if I managed it. Nevertheless, if some of you already have to manage a similar problem, I will be very happy to hear your solutions.

The app will run, in a first time, on Windows platform and should be adapted to MacOS, Linux, Android and iOS in later phases.

Comment: Are you deploying to VPS or dedicated servers? If so, you could run `aptget` or `yum` inside PHP to install the executables you need, with your end user entering the root password via your app.

Comment: If that approach is possible, then I'd put in a recommendation for Inkscape on the command line - it does an excellent job of conversion.

Comment: @halfer It could be a really good idea, but the app will be deployed as a exe provided to the client and installed in offline mode by an admin. Furthermore, the app as to run on Windows platforms. I forgot to mention it in the initial post, now edited. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Ah, it's an offline process too, okay - assumed it was a web app. Maybe use something like this Windows installer builder? http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Features

Comment: This tool seems to be good. I will do some tests for installing Inkscape and the app with nsis. To be honest, I would like to avoid to install an external tool. I'm afraid to miss a pb in the install process and to have a user unable to export his report. Furthermore, the adaptation to other platforms could be more complicated. I will try, think about it and let you know. Thanks

Comment: If you make sure you application is bulletproof in the case of problems with external dependencies, them you should be okay. Have a friendly message if it can't find Inkscape, and a feature that searches for it across the user's OS drive if the user indicates it is installed. In a wizard-type UI, even the most technophobic user should be able to cope with this.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple command line tool (wkhtml to pdf), that lets you convert html pages to pdf files. Its not strictly python/js solution, but you can call os.system() or something similar from python to use it. It helped me with my python program and it is very simple to use. Command is "wkhtmltopdf.exe inputname outputname" and you get what you want. And its free software. Site: https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems that wkhtmltopdf need to be installed first and, as I specified in question and comments, I would like to avoid any external tool install.